# C# & VS Code - Is it possible to "Run Test and Analyze Coverage" from the menu?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-coverage

[image]

On the testing menu above there's only a single option to run test `Run (Default)`. Is there a way to create a new option like `Run and Capture Coverage`?

If I click on `Configure Test Profiles` it only allows me to configure tests for Golang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.dotnet-test-explorer allows you to supply arguments to the execution of tests!